# Are Bökstedt's THH manuscripts available?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

In many papers dealing with topological Hochschild homology, the original unpublished manuscripts by Bökstedt are cited. To name one example, in McClure and Staffeldt's *On the topological Hochschild homology of $bu$*, 1989, we can see

> Topological Hochschild homology (Preprint, 1987)
>
> Topological Hochschild homology of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/p$ (Preprint, 1987)
>
> The natural transformation form $K(\mathbb Z)$ to $THH(\mathbb Z)$ (Preprint, 1987).

On Angeltveit & Rognes' *Hopf algebra structure on topological Hochschild homology*  only the first two are cited, but are attributed to "ca. 1986" and to the University of Bielefeld.

On Vogt's *Introduction to algebra over "brave new rings"*, again, only the first two appear, and attributed to 1985. And the list could go on.

Anyway, the question is, where could one get hold of these preprints?

EDIT: The question's been answered in the comments: I've got them sent to me. The question now is, shouldn't they be online for everybody to have access to them? I've no idea about copyright issues, etc.

Comment: I could e-mail them to you.

Comment: @AdeelKhan: thanks! You've got mail.

Comment: You could just email Bökstedt and ask him about putting his old preprints online.  He is still active, and his recent papers are on the arxiv, although it may be that his coauthors did the work of uploading them; he does not seem to have a home page that he maintains himself.  Maybe you could approach one of those coauthors and ask them to negotiate with Bökstedt.

Comment: I was about to ask this question as well. It's hard to believe that there are over two hundred citations to these preprints, and yet they are not available in any official source.